# Dictation with Android Wear Watch

Tags: android-wear

I know little about the Android Wear Watches, and want to know if I would be able to use it for dictation. Specifically I want to use it to quickly record ideas while I'm in the middle of something where it's not practical to get out my phone and do it.

Does it have a microphone, and would it be able to do speech recognition? And how quick/easy would it be to make it start recording/interpreting? I would probably have my phone in my pocket, paired by bluetooth, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Wear watch has a feature called: `OK Google... your_command`. To use it download **Google Now** on your android phone. You can talk to your watch anytime you want and use commands like:

- `set an alarm`
- `set a timer for 10 minutes`
- `call Steve`
- `text Steve, how are you?`
- `open <your_app>` //example: `open Google Maps`
- `take a note, buy cat food at the supermarket.`
- `remind me over 10 minutes, buy cat food at the supermarket.`
- `hello` //use this command to see a list of available commands.

Hope my answer helps you!